# Extract URL from m3u playlist in bash

Tags: bash

I have a m3u playlist where the URLs are changing weekly. I want to make a bash script to update m3u8 files on my server with these updated links. The playlist is like this:

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://www.test.com/logo1.png" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT" tvg-id="test1" tvg-name"test1",test1
https://test.com/test1.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="http://www.test.com/logo2.png" group-title="ENTERTAINMENT" tvg-id="test2" tvg-name"test2",test2
https://test.com/test2.m3u8
```

If I want to only extract https://test.com/test1.m3u8 how would I do that?

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `egrep` to extract those URLs

`egrep "^https.*m3u8$" your-playlist`

should return

```
https://test.com/test1.m3u8
https://test.com/test2.m3u8
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
grep .m3u8 test.txt
```